# I am not getting an option to close the window in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So, this is a simple code written to make the window and the background image. I need help with 2 things. 1. I am not getting the option to close, minimize or maximize the window, the entire thing is covered with my background image. 2. I need help in not making my image so bloated, or stretched. It is quite high-res but I believe I have made it stretched.

Code is below:

```
import pygame as p
import time
import random
import sys

# Defining global variables

HEIGHT = 800
WIDTH = 1000

# Adding a background image
BACKGROUND = p.image.load("background_image.jpg")


def draw():
    WINDOW.blit(BACKGROUND, (0, 0))
    p.display.update()


# Making the window
WINDOW = p.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
p.display.set_caption("Space Dodge")


# Window will quit after pressing the X
def main():
    run = True
    while run:
        for event in p.event.get():
            if event.type == p.QUIT:
                run = False
                break

        WINDOW.fill((0, 0, 0))
        draw()

    p.quit()
    sys.exit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ther is a **problem with your height of the screen.**
The Option are available but it is not visible in you screen.

#### Solution : **Reduce the HEIGHT and run the code Sure It will work.**